# Click outside drop-down and close drop-down react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

I have a demo App and want to close the drop-down when click anywhere outside.

Just a simple code.

Here is my demo app link of codesandbox

[Click Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-glade-g7w9b?file=/src/card.js:141-1297)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const checkIfClickedOutside = e => {   
      if (toggle && dropDownRef.current && !dropDownRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
        setToggle(false)
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", checkIfClickedOutside)
    }
  }, [toggle])
```

Comment: can you explain my little bit so i can use this in Class based component also.

Comment: In a class based component you'll need to use componentDidUpdate instead of the useEffect hook, I suggest reading this article for further understanding - 
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html
In a class component you'll have to use also the componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount lifecycle methods to add and remove the click eventListener

Comment: Please Check this and help https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-rubin-n44pb?file=/src/card.js

Comment: there you go - 
https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-hellman-rp7yt?file=/src/card.js